# fluentPDO записи за последние 24 часа?

Tags: mysql

На сайте используется fluentPDO. Каким кодом можно вытащить записи за последние 24 часа? 
В базе created_at (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: Не знаю причем тут fluentPDO но в MySQL их получают `created_at >= now() - interval 1 day`

Comment: Для построения запросов используется https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo
Без конструктора я знаю каким запросом вытащить нужные данные.

Comment: А какая разница что используется. там же можно условия для where передавать и как я погляжу весьма обычным способом `->where('...')` а тут даже условие целиком на стороне mysql работает, так что никаких доп параметров кроме текста условия даже не нужно

Comment: не, не работает

Comment: Что значит "не работает". Оно выбирает что то не то или возвращает какую нибудь ошибку. И кстати вы не сказали какого типа у вас поле create_at, может оно не datetime

Comment: Ну как это не сказал? В вопросе указан тип поля. Не работает - ошибку выдает.

Comment: Вот полный список типов данных MySQL http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Column_types.html среди них нет current_timestamp. А результат возвращаемый _функцией_ CURRENT_TIMESTAMP можно сохранять в поле любого типа и от того как он физически там лежит может зависеть запрос. Но у вас видимо что то другое, раз "ошибку выдает". И я к сожалению не провидец, не могу сказать ничего конкретного не видя что вы в итоге написали и главное, текста сообщения об шибке

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался в чем дело было.